# Docker Container issues on Digital Ocean. Why isn't the storage empty?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean

I pushed an image to the container registry on digital ocean without any problem.

Thereafter, I deleted the image and run the garbage collector.

Why do I still have 82% used storage without any image and nothing the garbage collector could delete?

I tried the Dashboard as well as the `doctl` CLI, but I'm not finding any data.

[image: Screenshot]